# Xcode 4 iPad simulator - changes not showing

Tags: ipad, xcode4

When I run a basic HelloWorld app using iPad simulator, none of my GUI changes are showing up. For example, I added a label and a text field, and when I run using the iPhone 4.3 simulator, I see these changes. However, when I run using the iPad 4.3 simulator, I see the original "My Universal App on IPad" text that was part of the boiler plate xib that XCode generated when I created the project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a different project type and it seemed to work ok on the iPad simulator. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are issues with syncing resources - if you either delete the app from within the simulator, or just do a reset on the simulator all should be well.

If that (or possible a clean and re-build) doesn't sort it, then I suspect the problem lies within the resource handling code itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed the app from the iPad, but it still does the same thing when I re-run it. When you try this on your XCode environment, do you get the same behavior? I can outline exact steps in my original question if that would be helpful.

Comment: @dcp To be honest, as I'm not encountering this problem I don't know how I could re-create the issue. Sorry I can't be of any more assistance. :-)